# Understanding Floating-point doc

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm reading the Python doc about [floating-point issues and limits](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

About halfway down the page it says:

> Interestingly, there are many different decimal numbers that share the same nearest approximate binary fraction. For example, the numbers 0.1 and 0.10000000000000001 and 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 are all approximated by 3602879701896397 / 2 ** 55. Since all of these decimal values share the same approximation, any one of them could be displayed while still preserving the invariant `eval(repr(x)) == x`.

In particular, what does it want to say with:

> Since all of these decimal values share the same approximation, any one of them could be displayed while still preserving the invariant `eval(repr(x)) == x`

Doesn't Python truncate float with more than 15 decimal digits? Any examples?

Comment: I don't get what you don't get... python follows the IEEE 754 standard. For a detailed explanation see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @Bakuriu: This is about text formatting, which is not part of the IEEE 754 standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that you get the same output for `repr()` no matter how many extra digits were originally supplied,

```
>>> repr(0.1)
'0.1'
>>> repr(0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625)
'0.1'
```

So, why doesn't it print the longer version for both?

```
# Hypothetically...
>>> repr(0.1)
'0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625'
>>> repr(0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625)
'0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625'
```

So, there are multiple ways to print out the same number.  Python uses the `dtoa()` function to choose the *shortest* way to print out a given number, and in this case, the shortest way is `0.1`.

`0.1` isn't actually exact: the exact result is the longer one, but `dtoa()` rounds the number off when printing it out, as long as the rounded number will be rounded back to the original number when it is read back in.  In other words,

```
float(repr(x)) == x
```

...even though both `float()` and `repr()` round their arguments.

Comment: I've never heard of `ntoa` in this context.  Typo?

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I think that's the name of the function.  I don't have a link.

Comment: I think you're looking for `dtoa` then, though the actual function is called `_Py_dg_dtoa` (but it's based on a function called `dtoa` from David Gay).

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Thanks, I just found it.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well, sorry, I'll try again.
In Python floating-point numbers are stored as binary fractions. Here, now, there is a problem because not all floats can be represented by a binary fractions (i.e decimal 0.1 can't), so what is stored is a value (in binary) that approximates the decimal value. This means that if I write `x = 0.1` then `repr(x) == x` returns false, as it is and this I understood. Now why in the doc do they talk about number with 100 decimal digits if Python truncates to the 15th?

Comment: @DietrichEpp my answer was for Mark Dickinson's answer

Comment: @antox: Yes, I know how floating-point numbers work, that is why I am trying to answer your question.  In Python 3, `repr(x) == x` is a type error, so I'm not sure what you are trying to say there.  Python does not "truncate to the 15th digit" but rather it prints the minimum number of digits to ensure that `float(repr(x)) == x`.

Comment: so if I write `x = 0.000000000000000011243544543789` does python try to store the number in the best way? I mean I see 15 digits only for printing reasoning, but internaly pythony stores all the digits, is it right?

Comment: @antox: Python does not store any digits in this case, it stores bits... with binary representation `0x3c69ed0469b1f5eb`.  Since this involves a base conversion, Python rounds off to 53 bits (not digits).  When it prints the number out, it has to convert it back to base 10, which also involves rounding, and chooses the smallest number of digits that makes the round trip exact.

Comment: @antox: If you want to use decimal numbers, with digits, and exact math, you need to use the `decimal` module.

Comment: @antox if you really want to see all the digits, use `'%1.54e' % x`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: 54 digits isn't enough for this particular `x`.  (In the worst cases of IEEE 754 binary64 floats, you can need to compute upwards of 700 significant digits to see an exact result.)

Comment: In Java, I use `new BigDecimal(d).toString()` as a convenient way of getting the exact decimal value of a `double` `d`. Is there an equivalent in Python? It might help clarify this question.

Comment: @MarkDickinson how do you figure that? Each binary digit can be represented by a decimal digit since 2 is one of the factors of 10. I used the `e` notation to make sure all the digits are significant and you don't have to worry about leading zeros. If I'm wrong give a counter example.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That only accounts for the mantissa.  There is also an exponent.  For example, 2^-1000 would take almost 700 digits.  2^+1000 would take 300.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan that's what the question is all about - `repr` would be the natural choice but it doesn't do it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Try x=1e-300. I can't show the exact value, because is has over 700 significant decimal digits, and does not fit in a comment. The problem is that converting something of the form n/(2^m) to a decimal fraction involves multiplying n by (5^m).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan and Dietrich Epp thanks for teaching me something.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: `Decimal(x)` does an exact conversion of a Python (double-precision) `float` `x` to decimal, at least for Python >= 2.7, so `from decimal import Decimal; print(Decimal(x))` is the corresponding easy way to see all the digits in Python.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Dietrich Epp's excellent answer, this answer specifically addresses the issue of "Doesn't Python truncate float with more than 15 decimal digits? Any examples?".

Consider the following Python session:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct  2 2013, 22:34:09) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = 0.10000000000000001249000902703301107976585626602172851562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
>>> x
0.10000000000000002
>>> y = 0.10000000000000001249000902703301107976585626602172851562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>> y
0.1
>>>
```

The literals assigned to `x` and `y` differ only in a very low significance digit - you will probably have to scroll to see it - yet `x` and `y` have different values. Obviously, that would not be the case if Python truncated based on 15 decimal digits.

Instead, it is picking the IEEE 64-bit binary floating point number closest to the decimal literal, with ties rounded to the one with a zero least significant fraction bit. I picked `y` to be exactly half way between two representable numbers, but rounding down. `x` is just a tiny bit bigger, so it rounds up.